# How to define CanCan abilities with model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using CanCan to define abilities in my app.

Question is how to define ability of a model that belongs to the User through an association.

For example this works because Campaign has an `affiliate_id` field

```
can :manage, Campaign, :affiliate_id => affiliate.id
```

However, `Affiliates` have `Subscriptions` and `Messages` through `Keywords`. `Keywords` belong to a `Campaign`.

All associations are working fine. However I'm not sure how to limit only `Subscriptions` and `Messages` to the `current_user`.

These are my current associations

```
# affiliate.rb
has_many :keywords, :through => :campaigns  
has_many :campaigns

# campaign.rb
belongs_to :affiliate
has_many :keywords
has_many :subscriptions, :through => :keywords
has_many :messages, :through => :subscriptions

# keyword.rb
has_many :subscriptions
has_many :messages
belongs_to :campaign

# message.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :campaign
belongs_to :subscription
belongs_to :keyword

# subscription.rb
belongs_to :campaign
belongs_to :affiliate
belongs_to :keyword
has_many :messages
```

Also, (bonus question), how can I show all objects if the user is admin? I have something like this but It's not retrieving all objects.

```
if affiliate.status == "admin"
  can :manage, :all
end
```

Comment: Can you post your actual AR associations? It might be easier than figuring it out through your description :)

Comment: Just updated my answer with current associations.

Comment: what about the user itself? And the question is how do I limit an ability on the current users messages and subscriptions, yes?

Comment: User is called Affiliate, yes that is the question.

Comment: And if is admin see all campaigns, messages and subscriptions no matter who made them.